# Accessing AWS Secrets Manager in Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, parsing, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I am accessing AWS Secrets Manager in Alpine Linux, though I can't see a way to get a value only from secret string without installing `jq` resource in Linux.

I know the below command will solve but jq is not a standard utility:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id secrets| jq --raw-output '.SecretString' | jq -r .<KeyName>
```

I'm stuck at checking the below command but it would return JSON format with 3 key-value pairs:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id secrets --query SecretString --output text
```

Also one option is to use Systems Manager Parameter Store which is possible but I don't like to create them 1-by-1 like in Secrets Manager you can store username, password, URL in one secret string.

Comment: just a few FYIs: you could also use python to interpret json from the command line, are you using a version of Alpine that has python?  Alpine is pretty bare bones so you don't have much to work with... you could also write something using sed/awk to pull out the key values if the JSON structure is very consistent.  your question isn't really a secrets manager question, it's more "how do I read JSON in alpine linux without installing any additional packages". you may want to search around this and you'll find a few other sources for your answer

Comment: your answer has the hints that i need. will try those options. thank you! @John Rotenstein

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like are correct using `jq`, since the AWS CLI cannot interpret that field.

This is because the `SecretString` field on a secret is a `string`, which is not interpreted by the AWS CLI as a JSON object:

```json
{
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-2:...:secret:foo-GZPisx",
    "Name": "foo",
    "VersionId": "...",
    "SecretString": "{\"my-key\":\"my-value\"}",      <-- This is a string
    "VersionStages": [
        "AWSCURRENT"
    ],
    "CreatedDate": 1601860373.721
}
```